# Import xml file Doctype

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am programming in the VBA source code a logic to import xml file DOCTYPE CFXML to excel, however I do not know which function to use to import.

I'm trying this command but it does not work:

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport Url: = sFile, ImportMap: = Nothing, Overwrite: = True, Destination: = Range ("$ A $ 1")
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE CFXML [
...
<ProductLineItem>
      <ProductLineNumber>1000</ProductLineNumber>
      <TransactionType>NEW</TransactionType>
      <CPUSIUvalue>1</CPUSIUvalue>
      <ProprietaryGroupIdentifier>1000</ProprietaryGroupIdentifier>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <ProductIdentification>
        <PartnerProductIdentification>
          <OrderedProductIdentifier>N/A</OrderedProductIdentifier>
          <ProprietaryProductIdentifier>9009- 
            22A</ProprietaryProductIdentifier>
          <ProductDescription>Server 1:9009 Model 22A</ProductDescription>
          <ProductTypeCode>Hardware</ProductTypeCode>
          <ProductIdentifierTypeCode>MTM-FC</ProductIdentifierTypeCode>
        </PartnerProductIdentification>
      </ProductIdentification>
...
```

I want to import the tags: ProductDescription, Quantity, MonetaryAmount, ProductTypeCode, ProprietaryProductIdentifier, ProductIdentifierTypeCode.

Comment: Note that *"it does not work"* is no usefull error description. Which error do you get and in which line. Please provide a [mcve]. • Actually there are too many spaces in the code. There must NOT be a space between `: =` and range addresses with spaces like `"$ A $ 1"` are not valid too. • Please read the documentation: [Workbook.XmlImport method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.xmlimport) for further instructions. The parameter `ImportMap` is required and cannot be `Nothing`

Comment: Remove the spaces from your range location. It should say `$A$1`. As long as your XML data is formatted properly, it should work.